# What is the 0, 0 Declaring, in ".setMargins(imgX, imgY, 0, 0)" ? Am I even understanding the X, Y coordinates correctly?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I'm currently trying to move an ImageButton to a certain X and Y location in my Android App. (Api level 15 to 22) and the size of the Image is not staying the same. Its distorting. I first assumed it was the declaring of 0, 0 in the following code:

```
marginParams.setMargins(imgX, imgY, 0, 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

So I tried to wrap content. But it did nothing!

```
marginParams.setMargins(imgX, imgY, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Here is all of the code if needed:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public EditText collectedTextEdit;
    public ImageButton candyEdit;
    public int collected = 0;
    public int screenWidth = 300;
    public int screenHeight = 300;
    public final int candySize = 50;
    Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        collectedTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.collectedText);
        candyEdit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.candy);
        collectedTextEdit.setText("Collected: " + collected);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        candyEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                collected += 1;
                collectedTextEdit.setText("Collected: " + collected);

                int candyX = random.nextInt(screenWidth);
                int candyY = random.nextInt(screenHeight);
                System.out.println(candyX + " : " + candyY);

                //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(candyEdit.getLayoutParams());
                marginParams.setMargins(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, candyX, candyY);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                //layoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                candyEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the declaration of the ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/candy"
        android:background="@drawable/candy"
        android:contentDescription="@string/candyImg"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/collectedText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/collectedText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/collectedText" />
```

Please help me! If you need any other code examples feel free to ask and I'll get right to it!

Comment: Can you show what your code with the imagebutton looks like?

Comment: Of course adding it now! :)

Comment: So out of curiosity, have you tried in the xml just making the height/width static? e.g. 30dp

Comment: Yes, I'll show when thats declared also